# How to check if string (current URL) includes a few substrings

Tags: angular, string, ecmascript-6

I need to check if current URL includes a few substrings. My code works but I need a tip if it possible to make it better. I realize that duplicating code is not a good practice. I am working with Angular 6/Typescript/ECMAScript 6.

```
const currentUrl = this.location.path();
const displayTile = currentUrl.includes('/search-resources') || currentUrl.includes('/calendar') || currentUrl.includes('/yearbooks')? 1 : 2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is just fine, if you want to reduce the length of checks, have the substrings in an array. like:

```
var substrings = ['/search-resources', '/calendar', '/yearbooks']
```

Test your condition using:

```
const displayTile = substrings.some((e) => currentUrl.includes(e)) ? 1 : 2
```

[Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

Comment: @NataliaGurgul: Please consider accepting answers if they solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has `$.inArray`

```
var names = ['search-resources', 'calendar'];
if ($.inArray('calendar', names) !== -1) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I don't use jQuery

Comment: @NataliaGurgul you can check this link for your better answer https://frontstuff.io/a-better-way-to-perform-multiple-comparisons-in-javascript